# I need help setting up string that reads from separate file in python

Tags: python, split

```
As you will read i have worked on this hard but am stuck!!!!!!
```

GETTING STARTED
Move into your cs170 directory and create a new directory called project3. Once in this directory, create a new Python script called movieDB.py. Once this script is created, you can use Vim to edit and save your changes.

Databases are implemented everywhere from web servers to automobiles, video games, smartphones, etc. The goal of this project is to implement a simple Python database and query system. You will read movie data from a file named movies.

Tasks for your program:

```
Display Movies
Display longest movie
Display shortest movie
Display oldest movie
Display newest movie
Display movies with specified rating
Quit
```

PROGRAM BEHAVIOR
Your program should use a menu driven interface that allows the user to interact with one table in a database. Once your program is launched, it should read in the file of movie information and then display the following menu:

```
Welcome to the Python Movie Database!
Main menu:
    1:  display all movies
    2:  display shortest movie
    3:  display longest movie
    4:  display oldest movie
    5:  display newest movie
    6:  display movies by rating
    0:  quit the program
Choice:
```

To populate your movieDB.py script with movie data, you will need to place the following content  into a file named movies:
The Matrix,Machines enslave humans with virtual reality,1999,136,R,Keanu Reeves and Laurence Fishburne,Wachowski Brothers
Pulp Fiction,Two thugs boxer and crime boss meet their fates,1994,154,R,John Travolta and Samuel L. Jackson,Quentin Tarantino
Blade Runner,Futuristic detective hunts obsolete androids,1982,122,R,Harrison Ford and Sean Young,Ridley Scott
    NOTE: There will always be exactly three records in movies file. The records above are given as a  test case. Your program should work correctly for a movies file with different movie records, as  long as it follows the given CSV format.

The records in movies are saved in comma-separated-values(CSV) format. This means each field of the record is separated from other fields using the comma( , ).

Each record will be formatted with fields in this order:

```
Title,Plot,Year,Runtime,Rating,Actors,Director
```

LOCATING ITEMS IN A STRING
    How do look for specific items in a string?

```
You can use the string split function. For example, if I have a string:

str = "this,is,a,string."
```

the split function can be used to "tokenize" items from the string. Tokenizing places items of a    string between delimiters into a list:

```
tokens = str.split(',')
```

Produces a list (the variable tokens is a list) of the items in the string delimited by commas. The result would be:

```
["this", "is", "a", "string."]
where tokens[0] --> "this", tokens[1] --> "is", and so on.
```

CAPTURING DATA FROM MOVIES AND RUNNING THE PROGRAM
To execute your program, you will need to capture the records stored in the movies file. You can    do this by using a function that creates a file pointer to the movies file. The populateMovies function creates a file pointer, fp. The function returns fp.readlines() which is a list where each item in the list is a line from the file. Template to get started:

```
def main():
  movies = populateMovies()
  print("data from movies:\n", movies)

#function that reads from the movies file, and returns a list of records
#input: none
#output: list
def populateMovies():
  fp = open("movies", "r")
  return fp.readlines()

main()
Now you can execute your program:

$python3 movieDB.py
Option 1: Display all movies
```

Option 1 will display the entire contents of the movie database. Based on the test movies file, when you select the first option, your program should display something similar to:

The Matrix Machines enslave humans with virtual reality 1999 136 R Keanu Reeves and Laurence Fishburne Wachowski Brothers
Pulp Fiction Two thugs boxer and crime boss meet their fates 1994 154 R John Travolta and Samuel L.    Jackson Quentin Tarantino
Blade Runner Futuristic detective hunts obsolete androids 1982 122 R Harrison Ford and Sean Young    Ridley Scott

Option 2: Display shortest movie
This option displays the shortest movie in the database. You will need to search your list of      movies to find the shortest one. Note that the Runtime is in the same place for each of the three records.

Option 3: Display longest movie
Like option 2, but displays the longest movie.

Option 4: Display oldest movie
Option 4 should display the movie that has the oldest production date.

Option 5: Display newest movie
Like option 4, but displays the movie with the newest production date.

Option 6: Display movies by rating
This option should prompt the user for a rating:

Display movies with what rating? PG
The program then displays the movies with the given rating.

Option 7: Quit

After each option displays its corresponding result, the user should be returned to the main    menu.
Option 7 gives the user the ability the exit the program.

```
CODING STYLE
Your main function will never explicitly use <, <=, >, or >=.

All logic should be confined to functions that are losely coupled (low number of formal    parameters).




I have set up database with specific info:  

- Title
- Plot
- Year
- Runtime
- Rating
- Actors
- Director  

If I type `info` in `str = "......"`, I can get it to work. However, I cannot get string to come     from file named `movies`. Please Help! Here is my logic.

import os

def main():
  movies = populateMovies()
  displayMovieMenu()



def populateMovies():
  fp = open("movies", "r")
  return fp.readlines()


def displayMovieMenu():
  print("Welcome to the Python Movie Database!")
  while(True):
    print("\n1: Display all movies")
    print("2: Display shortest movie")
    print("3: Display longest movie")
    print("4: Display oldest movie")
    print("5: Display newest movie")
    print("6: Display movies by rating")
    print("7: Quit the program")
    choice = int(input("Choice: "))
    if(choice == 1):
      print("Data from movie database:\n",movies)
    if(choice == 2):
      print("Shortest movie is: ",shortestMovie())
    if(choice == 3):
      print("Longest movie is: ",longestMovie())
    if(choice == 4):
      print("Oldest movie is: ",oldestMovie())
    if(choice == 5):
      print("Newest movie is: ",newestMovie())
    if(choice == 6):
      print(input("Make a rating selection: "))
      return ratingMovie()
    if(choice == 7):
      break

def shortestMovie():
  f = open("movies","r")
  str = list(f)
  for line in str:
    tokens = str.split(',') 
  while(True):
    if(tokens[3] < tokens[10]) and (tokens[3] < tokens[17]):
      return tokens[0]
    elif(tokens[10] < tokens[3]) and (tokens[10] < tokens[17]):
      return tokens[7]
    else:
      return tokens[14]
```

It works when typed like this:

```
def longestMovie():
  str = "The Matrix,Machines enslave humans with virtual reality,1999,136,R,Keanu Reeves and Laurence Fishburne,Wachowski Brothers,Pulp Fiction,Two thugs boxer and crime bossmeet their fates,1994,154,R,John Travolta and Samuel L. Jackson,Quentin Tarantino,Blade Runner,Futuristic detective hunts obsolete androids,1982,122,R,Harrison Ford and Sean Young,Ridley Scott."
  tokens = str.split(',')
  while(True):
    if(tokens[3] > tokens[10]) and(tokens[3] > tokens[17]):
      return tokens[0]
    elif(tokens[10] > tokens[3]) and (tokens[10] > tokens[17]):
      return tokens[7]
    else:
      return tokens[14]


def oldestMovie():
  str = "The Matrix,Machines enslave humans with virtual reality,1999,136,R,Keanu Reeves and Laurence Fishburne,Wachowski Brothers,Pulp Fiction,Two thugs boxer and crime bossmeet their fates,1994,154,R,John Travolta and Samuel L. Jackson,Quentin Tarantino,Blade Runner,Futuristic detective hunts obsolete androids,1982,122,R,Harrison Ford and Sean Young,Ridley Scott."
  tokens = str.split(',')
  while(True):
    if(tokens[2] > tokens[9]) and(tokens[2] > tokens[16]):
      return tokens[0]
    elif(tokens[9] > tokens[16]) and (tokens[9] > tokens[2]):
      return tokens[7]
    else:
      return tokens[14]

def newestMovie():
  str = "The Matrix,Machines enslave humans with virtual reality,1999,136,R,Keanu Reeves and Laurence Fishburne,Wachowski Brothers,Pulp Fiction,Two thugs boxer and crime bossmeet their fates,1994,154,R,John Travolta and Samuel L. Jackson,Quentin Tarantino,Blade Runner,Futuristic        detective hunts obsolete androids,1982,122,R,Harrison Ford and Sean Young,Ridley Scott."

  tokens = str.split(',')
  while(True):
    if(tokens[2] < tokens[9]) and(tokens[2] < tokens[16]):
      return tokens[0]
    elif(tokens[9] < tokens[2]) and (tokens[9] < tokens[16]):
      return tokens[7]
    else:
      return tokens[14]

def ratingMovie():
  str = "The Matrix,Machines enslave humans with virtual reality,1999,136,R,Keanu Reeves and               Laurence Fishburne,Wachowski Brothers,Pulp Fiction,Two thugs boxer and crime bossmeet their     fates,1994,154,R,John Travolta and Samuel L. Jackson,Quentin Tarantino,Blade Runner,Futuristic detective hunts obsolete androids,1982,122,R,Harrison Ford and Sean Young,Ridley Scott."
  tokens = str.split(',')
    while(True):
      if(tokens[5] == 'R'):
        return tokens[0]
      if(tokens[12] == R or PG or G):
        return tokens[7]
      if(tokens[19] == R or PG or G):
        return tokens[14]
      else:
        break

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the `movies` folder this way:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('/home/mou/webPages')
['searchButton.png', 'close.png', 'JavaScript-2', '.~lock.steps.xlsx#', 'jquery_libs', 'app.js~', '.ropeproject', 'search.png', 'JS', 'JavaScript-4', 'index.html~', '.metadata', 'colors', 'Javascript-3', 'JavaScript-1']
>>>
```

As you can see it returns a list, so you won't have to convert it to a `list`.

Comment: Maybe this will help. I have the concept but am brand new at this.

Comment: `'/home/mou/webPages'` is for linux file system. If you are on a Windows machine, the file path convention is `C:/path/to/your/folder`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, however, I think I have some type of syntax or logic error. If you can figure it out, I will make it worth your effort.